# Many Azure PowerShell commands fail: Must specify valid information for parsing in the string

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-powershell

Today we tried to deploy new build to our staging environment which based on Azure Web Apps using our release flow which normally runs good and requires to push one button. but today something is going wrong with Azure. the commands like Get-AzureWebSiteJob, Switch-AzureWebSiteSlot, Start-AzureWebsiteJob go crazy and return error like:

```
"Start-AzureWebsiteJob : Must specify valid information for parsing in the string."
```

after second third fourth attempt error is gone but is it normal situation ? and we should handle that using retry strategy ? or something went wrong with likely Service Management cmdlets?
It is really sad to see that because you never know when Azure cmdlets would like to go down....

- PowerShell 5.0
- Azure PowerSherr Module 4.3.1
- Subscription in North Europe

Command:

```
Start-AzureWebsiteJob -Name "lms365-dirreader-prod-northeuropestage" -JobName "DirectoryReader-OnSchedule"
```

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to show the exact command you're executing (without access keys or real names of course). Maybe it's that you're using a special character? Maybe there was a transient outage (as reported in the [Azure Dashboard](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/)) during this period of time and was completely unrelated to the PowerShell cmdlets?

Comment: Updated. Likely it is unrelated because the same commands on the same machine run well in 99% of cases. But  the error is not so informative. Personally I would like not to make such decision like If 'Must specify valid information for parsing in the string' then it is something wrong with azure :) thanks for your intention to help!